# Importing JotForms

Tags: cognito-forms

I am growing increasingly unsatisfied with the JotForms. While their support is second to none, I am finding some relatively basic features and tasks are difficult to implement without dusting off my coding kills or hiring a 3rd Party Developer.

However, a lot of time and effort has gone into creating some complex forms that use conditions and calculations. Therefore, I fear the transition will be lengthy and expensive.

Do you have any tools to convert or import forms from JotForm?

Comment: The developers for Cognito are usually around, but I think this question is a bit too broad as it stands.  We don't normally take requests for apps, but I will see what they have to say and whether this should be sent to their customer service instead.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood where I was. I thought I was asking a specific question to Cognito. Think I'll take try to reach them directly.

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports automatically [importing forms from Wufoo](https://www.cognitoforms.com/l/wufoo-alternative), but does not yet have a [JotForm importer](https://www.cognitoforms.com/l/jotform-alternative).  This is on our public [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/MaDnylH6/6-import-form-design?menu=filter&filter=change), so please upvote and provide examples of types of forms you would like to import.